# Magento 2 include xmlToArrayParser php library and use it in module

Tags: magento-2.1, 3rd-party-library

I want to include below php library in my custom module

https://github.com/Robhub/trocutc/blob/master/incl/xmlToArrayParser.class.php

and want to use the same in controller or helper.

I have included the class file in Lib folder as lib/xmlToArrayParser/xmlToArrayParser.php but what to do further.

How this can be done.